# Using variable as value in object assignment - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

If we have the following code

```
<ul>
    <li id='car'>ok</li>
    <li id='color'>dd</li>
</ul>
```

I can apply a name attribute directly with the following code

```
car.setAttribute('name', 'bmw');
```

However what if I want to use a variable in the place of car.

```
var z = 'car';
z.setAttribute('name', 'bmw');
```

This doesn't work. Or harder still, what about using both?

```
var z = 'r';
ca + z.setAttribute('name', 'bmw');
```

Also doesn't work.

Is this possible?

Comment: c is a string. setAttribute is a [DOM element method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp). What are you expecting to happen exactly?

Comment: c is a string. it doesn't have a `setAttribute` method. That'd be something in a DOM object. you'd want `var c = document.getElementById('car'); c.setAttribute(...)`

Comment: is `name` a valid `LI` attribute? I don't think so.

Comment: When I statically type the id *car.setAttribute* it works, so I am trying to pass a variable in place of car, *var.setAttribute*

Comment: @gummage you mean (correct me if I'm wrong) you want to `setAttribute` to an empty `variable` ??

Comment: because ids are available globally as variables that represent the dom elements.You can't just access them as strings (if you have this: `var x = {'foo': 'bar'}` you can do `x.foo` but you can't do `"x".foo`)

Comment: @gummage I mean, `'car'` is a string and `.setAttribute()` does *not* apply to Strings. What are you actually trying to achieve? Is there a mystique reason for all that?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan T.J Crowder provided a answer - *window[ca + 'r'].setAttribute('name', 'car');* however because of the global advice he gave, I will do it differently.

Comment: @gummage ohh I see now, but than your question is a bit misleading. I would ask rather: "Given `foo` is a variable, how to point to that variable using String `"foo"`. Any way this question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're relying on the automatic globals that browsers create for elements that have `id`s (which I **don't recommend**). If so, you can do it by using the `window` object:

```
var c = 'car';
window[c].setAttribute('name', 'car');

var ca = 'ca';
window[ca + 'r'].setAttribute('name', 'car');
```

All global variables are properties of the global object, which you can access as `window` on browsers. (In fact, `window` itself is a property of the global object, which it uses to refer to itself.) In JavaScript, you can refer to properties on objects using dot notation and a literal name (`obj.foo`), or bracketed notation and a *string* name (`obj["foo"]`). In the latter case, the string can be the result of any expression, including a variable lookup.

I don't recommend relying on automatic globals, though, the global namespace is **really** crowded and other things (declared variables, functions) can shadow the elements. Use `getElementById` instead:

```
var c = 'car';
document.getElementById(c).setAttribute('name', 'car');

var ca = 'ca';
document.getElementById(ca + 'r').setAttribute('name', 'car');
```

---

Side note: `name` isn't a valid attribute for [`li` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element).

Answer (score 2):

Use `document.getElementById` to look up the element:

```
document.getElementById(c).setAttribute('name', 'car');

document.getElementById('ca' + c).setAttribute('name', 'car');
```

Comment: `setAttribute` is a method of DOM elements.

Comment: That's different from what he's trying to do in the question, so I don't think it's relevant.

Comment: OK, given he's got HTML there I suppose it's a fair assumption after all.

Answer (score 1):

You can't (without resorting to `eval`) access local variables by string.

You *can* (**but shouldn't**) do it with global variables, or if the variable in question is actually a property of another object (the former being a special case since global variables are in reality properties of the `window` object), i.e.:

```
var o = {};
o.car = document.getElementById('car');
o.color = document.getElementById('color');

var c = 'car';
o[c].setAttribute('name', 'bmw');
```